# Why InputFieldState does not work in viberbot 1.0.12

Tags: viber-api, viber-bot, viber-bot-python

I expected the field to disappear from the user interface, but it remains
How do I remove the field for input field?

```
def handle_message(sender_id):
    message = KeyboardMessage(keyboard=create_menu())
    viber_api.send_messages(sender_id, [message])
```

```
def create_menu():
    keyboard = {
        "Type": "keyboard",
        "InputFieldState": "hidden",
        "Buttons": [
            {
                "Columns": 2,
                "Rows": 1,
                "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
                "Text": "<b>Button 1</b>",
                "TextSize": "large",
                "TextVAlign": "middle",
                "TextHAlign": "center",
                "ActionType": "reply",
                "ActionBody": "button1",
                "Silent": True
            },
        ],
    }

    return keyboard
```

I expected the keyboard to disappear from the user interface, but it remains

Answer (score 0):

I should have added the argument min_api_version=6 to KeyboardMessage

```
message = KeyboardMessage(keyboard=create_menu(), min_api_version=6)
```